# Batch File Iterating through files on a local network server

Tags: windows, networking, command-line, batch-file

I'm trying to open various files stored on a local network server with this piece of batch code:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /b /a:d "\\server\directory\*"') do %%G\setup.xml
```

but since `dir \\server\directory` doesn't work so won't that piece of code.
How can I accomplish that?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why not use powershell instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map a drive using

```
net use X: \\server\directory
```

and then you can change to that directory using

```
pushd X:
```

You can then run your batch command on the current directory, and when you are finished and the files are no longer in use, you can delete the drive using

```
net use X: /delete
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought about that, but since I have to edit the files I'm opening I cant do a `popd` right after the `for` loop... but still I'd like to remove the virtual disk once I finished editing the files. How can I do that? Two separate batch files maybe?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you are trying to do. What would you use 2 batch files for?

Comment: I want to elimnate the virtual disk made with pushd after I finished editing the files I opened

Comment: Or you could map the drive beforehand with `net use` then you know which drive to delete afterwards.

Comment: I can't `popd` after because the virtual drive will disappear and so the opened file (to be clear: notepad++ will tell me "the file no longer exists....blabla"). I will search the `net use` and see how it works, thank you.

Comment: Ah right. Yeah try `net use X: \\server\dir`, then you can delete it `net use X: /delete` whenever you want to, and just `pushd X:\` instead.

Comment: I think this meets my needs. Can you update your answer so I can tick it? Thank you very much!

Comment: Oh one more thing: in the .bat where I write `net use X: /delete` how do I tell him to say YES to the question that always makes after deleting?

Comment: Do you mean you want confirmation to delete the drive, or cmd asks for confirmation?

Comment: cmd asks for confirmation and I want to automatically say yes. Is it possible?

Comment: Oh right, it didn't ask for me, it just did it. Try `echo y| net use X: /delete`

Answer (score 0):

You write:

> since dir \server\directory doesn't work

At first I was going to say that does work. But what actually works is:

```
dir \\server\sharename
```

The server has to share the directory. On the server you can use a command like:

```
net share public=c:\public
```

The you should be able to:

```
dir \\server\sharename
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see what you mean... unfortunately I can't run commands directly from the server. I have access just to the files.

Comment: So the server has already made the files available via a sharename? I want to let you know, on my system I can run your example without problem (well, I changed it to echo %%G, worked fine). Maybe the program you're running will not access files via sharename.

Comment: If I get what you mean with sharename, no. To access the files I go to "Network" and wait for the shared computers to appear and when the server appears I double click it and explore it.