# Zip files with encryption in a remote share, keeping orignal names and location

Tags: powershell, batch-file, automation, 7zip

My team faces the need to encrypt all files in a repository with AES256. For this purpose, we decided we are going to zip all files with such encryption, using the same key for all of them.

The problem we have is that these files sit in a NAS, so from windows boxes they are accessible by \ to them.

The directory structure is something like this:

```
 Original Structure:
 Root
 -1
  |--folder1
    |---file1.ext
    |---file2.ext
  |--folder2
    |---filea.ext
    |---fileb.ext
   |--folder2.a
    |---filec.ext

 and so on...
```

Essentially, what we need is to have all the original files contained in a zip file, keeping their original names, which would be something like this:

```
 Desired Outcome:
 |-Root
  |-1
    |--folder1
       |---file1.zip
       |---file2.zip
    |--folder2
       |---filea.zip
       |---fileb.zip
      |--folder2a
       |---filec.zip
 and so on...
```

To accomplish this, we tried a batch script that calls 7zip, but it only works if it's run from the root directory, which is something we cannot use as the files are not in a server.

Here is the syntax of the batch script we came up with:

```
 FOR /R %%i IN ("*.wmv") DO "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -mx0 -tzip -pPasswordHere "%%~dpni.zip" "%%i"
```

But, as wrote previously, it only works when run from the root folder, which is something we cannot do as files sit on a network location.
Mapping the drive or making a symbolic link to it doesn't do the trick either.

I've also checked on 7zip to do this, namely, making use of its "-r" operator, but I couldn't find a way to get the desired outcome (namely, recurse through all folders in the remote tree structure -there are a lot of them...- and keep the original file name).

I'm open to any suggestions as any kind of script, trick or guizmo that gets the job done will be more than welcome. =)

Thanks a million in advance!,
Sebas.

Comment: `FOR /R "C:\startfolder\" %%i IN ( ...` ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!. I tried that as my first option, but it didn't work with either a local folder nor a network share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

----SOLUTION----

I actually found a sollution here, mapping the drive in a different way (it's so simple it just made me feel stupid(er), but it's altogheter beautiful).

Using the batch script below, the remote share can be mapped like so:

```
  You can map a drive using

  net use X: \\server\directory
  and then you can change to that directory using

  pushd X:
```

(Post from which the answer was taken from: [Batch File Iterating through files on a local network server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212178/batch-file-iterating-through-files-on-a-local-network-server))