# Batch file can't list files in server directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, server

I'm new to the batch file scripting world and I'm trying to list the files of a server directory (my final goal is to search for a specific file within that folder -including subfolders-. I am only trying to list files just as a way of confirming that I am accessing the server folder) but I am stuck and don't know how to solve this.

This is my attemp

```
dir "\\server\folder\*" /b /a-d
```

I also tried `"\\server\folder"`, `"\\server\folder\*.*"`, `\\server\folder` to no avail.

I tried using this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/14212254/19569763 but it throws an error about multiple connections (I the used `net use` to check and it returned "no connections")

I run the `.bat` file locally since I get a warning message if I try to do it within the server and I'm not risking the company server to do that.

Honestly, I haven't worked with servers before so I'm probably making multiple basic or stupid mistakes or I'm not considering certain things that are obvious to someone with experience here.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried, ```@PushD "\\server\folder" 2>NUL && (Dir /A:-D /B /S & PopD)```?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to all this. Could you walk me through what those things do? I haven't tried that since I don't understand half of it. If you could please break it for me I would appreciate it.

Comment: Create an ANSI encoded text file containing **only** the single line I've advised above. Save it with the name `testver.cmd`, then open a Command Prompt window, type `P:\athTo\testver.cmd`, and press the `[ENTER]` key.

Comment: But what does that line of code do? I'm a newbie here and curious to learn about this.

Comment: It should perform the task you've laid out above. If it doesn't `\\Server\Folder` is not available/accessible. To find out what almost any command does, open a Command Prompt window, type the command, followed by its help option, (usually `/?`). Examples, `PushD /?`, `Dir /?`, `PopD /?`.

Comment: It returns the same thing as it did before: "File not found"/"Cannot find file" (I'm translating so I don't know what the proper wording would be in English)

Comment: There are no files in that directory or its substructure then! Also, at no point had you previously told anyone here that you were receiving a `File Not Found` message, so we weren't able to guess that!

Comment: The thing is, there are multiple folders there and that is why I'm puzzled as to what is happening here.

Comment: Folders, are not files! If you want to see those use `@PushD "\\server\folder" 2>NUL && (Dir /A:D /B /S & PopD)` instead of `@PushD "\\server\folder" 2>NUL && (Dir /A:-D /B /S & PopD)`.

Comment: That worked! How can I list the files within those folders as well?

Comment: There are no files in those directories, the `Dir` command has already told you that! If you want to see everything in there use `@PushD "\\server\folder" 2>NUL && (Dir /A /B /S & PopD)`

Comment: But there are. When I access one of the folders I can see more folders and four files (two .bat and two .R ones)

Comment: If I change the path to "\\server\folder\subfolder" it returns nothing, not even "File not found" and that subfolder actually does have folders and files inside. I'm sorry but I don't know what is happening here. I'm completely lost.

Comment: I found the issue. My path had a special character (á). I changed it to the regular "a" and worked. Now I need to tackle the finding the file thing.

Comment: You should not need to change a letter, what you should do is to run the script using the same codepage you saved the script using. So make sure you save the script as ANSI/DOS encoded, _(not Unicode)_, with say codepage 1252, _(as it includes that character)_. Then at the start of your batch file add this line, ```@For /F "Tokens=*" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com') Do @For %%H In (%%G) Do @If Not %%~nH Equ 1252 %SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com 1252 1>NUL```.